Does the EU stamp passports when travelling to and from Andorra?
My passport is starting to get quite full, but is still valid for several years.  Later this year I expect to have to cross the Schengen / Andorra border several times.  I know Andorra doesn't stamp passports, but does the EU stamp passports when leaving and entering the Schengen Area to and from Andorra?  I'm guessing not, but it would be good know more certainly as it will affect when I need to renew my passport.  I will be travelling using a UK passport.
(While this is arguably a duplicate of this question, none of the answers there address the question of Schengen stamps – just Andorran ones.)

(+1) Doesn't really matter but for the most part the EU relies on member states to implement its rules so it would be France and Spain doing the stamping.

So far neither France, Spain or Andorra have ever checked, let alone stamped, any passports on any of my trips in the last two years.
Coach services will collect and submit a passenger manifest to Andorra and won't stop at the border unless requested which would be needed if someone wanted a Schengen exit stamp.

Thanks.  Just what I wanted to hear.  If I happen to get one during a random border check, that's no problem, but eight stamps in a week would really ruin my plans.

Since the nationals of Andorra, Monaco and San Marino are exempt from the passport stamp requirement (Schengen Border Code Article 11 (3)(e)), probably 99% of the daily traffic doesn't require any form of immigration check.

@MarkJohnson – Interesting (though totally irrelevant) that the Vatican is not also listed.
